# What is important about $\mathsf{Top}$ with regard to models of a homological variety?

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra

*Originally from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882714/what-is-important-about-mathsftop-with-regard-to-models-of-a-pointed-protom)*.

Consider an algebraic theory whose category of models in $\mathsf{Set}$ is homological. This is equivalent to saying that the theory has a unique constant $0$ and there exists an $n\geq 1$ such that:

- there are $n$ binary operations $\alpha_i$ such that $a_i(x,x) = 0$
- there is a $n+1%$-ary operation $\theta$ with $\theta(\alpha_1(x,y),\dots, \alpha_n(x,y),y) = x$

Then the category of models in $\mathcal{X} := \mathsf{Top}$ is homological, complete and cocomplete. For example this is the case for the category of topological groups.

> What's so special about $\mathsf{Top}$? What kind of other categories
>   $\mathcal{X}$ yield similar results?

The category of models of a protomodular theory in a lex (finitely complete) category is protomodular according to the nLab. This settles a part of the question.

Comment: "Algebraic variety" might not be the best choice of words, since this has a very different meaning elsewhere; I'd use "variety of algebras" (or even just "algebraic theory" or "Lawvere theory").

Comment: In the case where the theory $T$ is Mal'cev, it seems a crucial property is that coequalizers in $Top^T$ are *open surjections*. As regular epis, open surjections have the crucial property of being stable under pullback, and ultimately this is the reason why $Top^T$ is regular (despite the fact $Top$ is not). Perhaps something similar is true for more general homological theories, that accounts for regularity of topological models. (But maybe you know this already?)

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, see also results 10.10, 10.11, and 10.12 given on page 47 here: http://www.math.yorku.ca/~tholen/HB07BournClementino.pdf  I'm not sure if this is the type of answer you want though.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I need time to digest this since I am actually not familiar with  topology.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Well, I have yet to understand the proof (busy studying the things im supposed to study). But rereading the corresponding proof given in "Mal’cev, protomodular, homological and semi-abelian categories" it seems the argument really depends on topological concepts, possibly (I'm guessing) the notion of a topological construct. A more general theorem involving topological constructs would be definitely (!) nice (not that I would understand it right now). Though initally I hoped there would be a way more general theorem lurking somewhere.

Comment: Well, I expect that if an algebraic theory $T$ is homological in the sense of your post, then $\text{Mod}_T(\mathcal{X})$ should be a homological category provided $\mathcal{X}$ is regular. So that's a pretty wide class of categories. In some sense the fact that $\text{Mod}_T(\text{Top})$ is homological is a small miracle (because $\text{Top}$ itself doesn't enjoy good exactness properties), and so I guess the real question is: what about $\text{Top}$ allows this miracle to come about, despite the poor behavior of $\text{Top}$?

Comment: @ToddTrimble Yes, that is basically what I'm asking. And I'm guessing it works a little bit more generally with (concrete) categories that share important properties with $\mathsf{Top}$ (convergence spaces, uniform spaces, metric spaces?). So you could interpret my question as: "What is a general theorem that ensures $\operatorname{Mod}_T(\mathcal X)$ is homological in (some of) these cases?". I would already be very happy with an answer to this question. - Though on the other hand you can also interpret my question as: "Why these kinds of categories? Why not something completely different?"